# CSS pseudo-element in inline attribute style

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, inline-styles

I have tried with the sample below from the url. What I trying is to apply css pseudo-element in inline attribute, style. Somehow, it seems not working. I would appreciate for any advice.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css-style-attr-20010305

```
    <p style="{color: green; width: 10em} ::first-letter {float: left; font-size: 300%}">

This is an example of a paragraph with inline style attribute rules to create a spot effect, in this case, a drop-cap first letter.

</p>
```

Comment: You can't apply properties to pseudo-elements or pseudo-classes inline. You have to use embedded or linked CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not possible. The working draft you are referring to is over 12 years old. Click on the link “Latest version” in it, and you’ll find the [CSS Style Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/), a W3C Recommendation (“W3C standard”). It was approved recently. It contains no changes to the `style` attribute as in HTML specs, and this is indeed the message: the attribute has not been enhanced, and there are no plans to do so.

The conclusions depend on why you would use the construct. Normally, just assign an `id` attribute to the element and use an `id` selector in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way

```
<p style="color: green; width: 10em"><span style="float: left; font-size: 300%">L</span>orem Ipsum</p>
```