# How to set the css of the li:before with ng-style

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to change the width value of the li:before with a  variable scope (width).

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="step in stepsList" ng-style="{li:before { 'width': width;}"
        ng-class="{true: 'active'}[step.active]">
        <span>{{step.stepName | uppercase}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm doing this code but it's not working.
help please.

Comment: you can't. `style` does not work with pseudo-elements.

Comment: ngstyle uses inlinestyle so it is not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141374/using-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-with-inline-css

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138454/css-pseudo-element-in-inline-attribute-style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot have `pseudoelements` within `inline styling`. What you could do is have two sepparate `CSS Classes` like

```
.a:before {}
.b:before {}
```

This way you could use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to add the appropriate class to your HTML